# ionic 3 dateTime - displayFormat="HH:mm [Uhr]" converts the h in Uhr to time, how to ignore that?

Tags: date, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I think the title says it all.
You can input strings to the displayFormat, but all characters which can be converted into a date format (h, m, d,...) will be automatically replaced. Is there an option to ignore that like in moment.js with [] ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a good solution, but I have done it with "lookalike letters"

https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=h&r=None

Have a look at this converter.

I have used the ARMENIAN SMALL LETTER HO "հ" instead of "h"